# Idomatic way of using animateDpAsState in padding jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-animation, android-jetpack-compose-animation

I am learning [animateDpAsState](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/core/package-summary#animateDpAsState(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.animation.core.AnimationSpec,kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1)) from the doc. I did it without any problem, but I see a lot of recomposing happens. So I want to know what is the recommended way of doing this?

```
@Composable
private fun PaddingViewAnimation() {
    var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    val iconOffsetAnimation: Dp by animateDpAsState(
        if (visible) 13.dp else 0.dp, tween(1000)
    )
    PaddingViewAnimationStateLess(
        { iconOffsetAnimation },
        visible,
        onVisibleChange = {
            visible = it
        }
    )
}
```

**PaddingViewAnimationStateLess**

```
@Composable
fun PaddingViewAnimationStateLess(
    iconOffsetAnimation: () -> Dp,
    visible: Boolean,
    onVisibleChange: (Boolean) -> Unit,
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp)
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = iconOffsetAnimation()),
            imageVector = Icons.Default.ShoppingCart,
            contentDescription = null,
        )
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 10.dp),
            onClick = {
                onVisibleChange(!visible)
            },
        ) {
            Text(text = "Move Text")
        }
    }
}
```

When first time button click animation happens and I can see in layout inspector. I don't know this is normal or we can fix this problem. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of animating the top padding, you can do something different applying a y-translation with the `graphicsLayer` modifier with the lambda block that causes the layer properties update without triggering recomposition and relayout.

You can apply it to the `Column` or to each children.

Something like:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp)
        .graphicsLayer { translationY = iconOffsetAnimation().toPx() }
) {
    Image(
        imageVector = Icons.Default.ShoppingCart,
        contentDescription = null,
    )
    //....
}
```

Comment: It works!! Great you help me.

Comment: One question it solves for `PaddingViewAnimationStateLess` recompose count, but what about `Button` recompose count?

Comment: @VivekModi It should be resolved with the same code.

Comment: ohh yes. It'll solve I forgot to think. Thanks again..

Comment: Do you know how can I solve this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75662318/8266651)?

Comment: @VivekModi Thanks for feedback. I've to try some solutions.